# Full calendar Scheduler - get ResourceId on selecting the slotduration for adding events

Tags: fullcalendar, scheduler

In Scheduler Calendar, Iam getting the resources from resources.json on the first column.
Iam trying to add the events for each resources.
When I click the slotduration straight to each resources, I should get the resourceId.  So, I would know to which resources, Iam adding the events.

In select function, Iam able to get only the start and end time, but NOT the resourceId.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is fourth argument in the select callback, Using that you would be able to get resource. see the example below.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
select: function (start, end, calendar,res) 
{
     //to get resource 
    console.log(res);
}
});
```

It will give you  json object.

To get resource id on click of resource header do the following changes in scheduler.js,
modify below method.add id and class to the resource header.

```
 ResourceRow.prototype.renderSpreadsheetContent = function(tr) {
 .......
 .......
     td = $('<td id="'+resource.id+'" class="' + this.view.widgetContentClass + ' resourceHeader"/>').append(contentEl); // add id and class to the resource header.
 .......
 .......
   }
```

After changing the code just bind an event in your js file as below

```
     $(".resourceHeader").click(function(){
      var   resourceId=$(this).attr("id");
      //write a code to get all the events of selected resource 
      //and render it on calendar
     });
```

You are good to go now.
Thanks

Comment: This returns undefined result.

Comment: are you using sean kenny's  resource day view?

Comment: using fullcalendar scheduler timelineDay view.  
http://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/

Comment: Hey there, I went ahead and checked the API, there is fourth argument which gives you a resource in timeline view of calendar.

Comment: Hi.. tried the fourth argument too.  But it throws object object error. 
You can try this JSBin URL..
http://jsbin.com/raqumatesa/edit?js,output

Comment: Hey, Seems like they have added one more argument, I have updated the code on http://jsbin.com/yanadobowa/edit?js,output .

Comment: This works. 
Is it possible to click the resource title (first column) and get the ID?

Comment: Well you will need to modify scheduler.js file to achieve that. The simplest way to do is, add id attribute to each <td> of resource and bind an event with it.

Comment: any help can be provided here on scheduler.js

Comment: do you want to create an event when user click on any of the resource? or you just want to have an id of the resource?

Comment: I want resourceId, to list the event of selected resource.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have implemented this using onclick..
Below is the function (getme) used..

<div id="resbutton" onclick="getme('+this.resource.id+');" class="fc-cell-content" style="cursor:pointer;" title="'+(p?st(p):"&nbsp;")+'">